# How to update in mysql using python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

```
password = int(input("Enter your numeric password: "))
new_username = input("Enter your new username: ")
SQL_cmd = "UPDATE user_table SET Username = %s WHERE Password = %s" 
new_val = (SQL_cmd, new_username, password)
mycursor.execute(SQL_cmd1, new_val)
conn.comit()
```

While running this I get an error msg

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: You don't say what `SQL_cmd` is, but it shouldn't be in `new_val`, which should only contain the _values_ that you are passing to `cursor.execute`.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.execute(operation, params)` is expecting your query followed by parameters (values) to substitute..in your case, username then password. Take care with the order/amount of values in your new_val tuple, as right now you are inserting a non-existent variable (SQL_cmd) into the Username value of your query!

e.g. should be something like this:

```
password = int(input("Enter your numeric password: "))
new_username = input("Enter your new username: ")
SQL_cmd = "UPDATE user_table SET Username = %s WHERE Password = %s" 
new_val = (new_username, password)
mycursor.execute(SQL_cmd, new_val)
conn.commit()
```